# Delete row from classic report or interactive report apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to delete a record from classic report or interactive report. Note that the report was created using a collection how i can do that without submit page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, you would add some kind of hook in the report, such as a column with a "delete" icon. Then you could create a dynamic action that fires when the hook is clicked.

- The first action would be to confirm the delete.
- The second action would be Execute JavaScript which would transfer the primary key value from the row (perhaps from a hidden input) to a hidden (not protected) page item.
- The third action would be an Execute PL/SQL action that would do the delete. You'll put the hidden item's name in the action's Items to Submit attribute. That will allow you to get the latest value in session state before the PL/SQL code runs.

If you want someone to do this for you then you should help get them started by putting an example on apex.oracle.com or in your own APEX workspace on the [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/) and provide developer credentials.

Comment: I have this example that I should extend to include a mention of a prompt http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html

Comment: That's a perfect example... Thanks, Scott!